# Is there an iOS API that can identify which of your contacts are likely other iOS users?

Tags: ios, itunes

... for example, by finding your contacts that have iTunes logins.

Why? We're launching an app on iOS. We'd like a feature to allow users to connect with their friends who can download and install the app.

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest you might get (from the top of my head) is Game Center. All your friends on there are guaranteed to have an iOS device. Of course, not all iPhone owners use Game Center.

Comment: This is true now, but once Mavericks is released, this may not be 100% reliable any longer.

Comment: @RicPerrott I'd forgotten there is Game Center on the Mac. In fact it's there in Mountain Lion though I don't know of anyone who uses it!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because Apple uses it in their own apps:

- Messages - when typing in an email. The text will appear red if the email you want to iMessage is not setup with iMessage
- Find My Friends - same kind of thing

However it's probably a closed API that they're using. It's possible that they use the now deprecated [udid](/questions/tagged/udid) retrieval method.

You could try to query an Apple Server for the Apple ID and see what kind of response you get (just a shot in the dark there). Or you could search through GameCenter for a list of friends. Facebook might have some information on which users are iOS users too, take a look at their API and some Facebook profiles to see if theres anything you could check there.